# Find Google Console Access?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a working app with `GOOGLE_APP_ID` and `GOOGLE_APP_SECRET` but I cannot recall which account was used to manage these, and when I log in using my existing emails - I cannot find them (while they are still working)

How can I find out which email was used to manage the console that owns my existing keys?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to migrate that applicaton to another account.

Just open a ticket with google support and tell them the GOOGLE_APP_ID and ask how you can translate that application.

Maybe you can remember which account is by looking at the domain validation records on the DNS. But the safest bet is go to Google support.

Comment: Thanks, I cant find any way to contact them since its only regarding GCP Support and/or Google Maps

Comment: This answer is not correct. You must already be authenticated using the correct account to request support for that account. If you do not know the account to log in with, Google will not help you.

Comment: Google Support and Google Sales rep have the superpower to migrate this for you. You will need to open the ticket from the account you want to migrate the app to. They will also need proof that you're not scamming/hijacking someone else app, though.